# SQL Syntax Theory

Tags: sql

I'm dusting off my SQL knowledge and have been reviewing various tutorials.  One of the first tutorials demonstrated how to count the number of rows in a table by using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
```

Earlier though, the tutorial demonstrated returning all of the rows and columns from a table using:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

So, why wouldn't COUNT(*) return the total number of "cells" in the table?  For example, a table with three columns and five rows has fifteen "cells".  It would seem that COUNT(*) should return fifteen and not five.

Comment: Apple is round, Banana is long. Why not the other way round? Ans: Because that's the way they are

Comment: Because `SELECT COUNT(*)` returns the number of rows, (it counts the rows); the * means *let the database engine decide the best way to do so*. `SELECT *` means *select all the columns in the row* - the * means *all of the columns without naming each one individually*. IOW, they do two separate things even though they look similar. `COUNT(*)` is a function; `SELECT *` is not.

Comment: Why we need to know the total number of "cells"?

Comment: @ken-white, if you make your comment an answer, I'll mark it as useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT COUNT(*)` returns the number of rows, (it counts the rows); the `*` means let the database engine decide the best way to do so.

`SELECT *` means select all the columns in the row - the `*` means all of the columns without naming each one individually.

In other words, they do two separate things even though they look similar. `COUNT(*)` is a function (you `SELECT COUNT(*)` to use it); `SELECT *` is not.

Answer (score 0):

cells is not the interesting,  number of rows is,  to find cells, you just multiple by number columns.

`SELECT * FROM TABLE` will return all the rows,  if you have 10 million and all you want is the count, you don't want to have to fetch all 10 million rows.